# react-i18next getting error Attempted import error

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I tried to use https://react.i18next.com/
For localization and I am getting error: Attempted import error: 'initReactI18next' is not exported from 'react-i18next'.

This is my i18n.js file:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
// not like to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide 
// for passing in lng and translations on init

i18n
  // load translation using http -> see /public/locales (i.e. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react/public/locales)
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
  .use(Backend)
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    }
  });


export default i18n;
```

My package.json

> {   "name": "heatmann",   "version": "0.1.0",   "private": true,
>   "dependencies": {
>       "axios": "^0.19.0",
>       "i18next": "^19.4.5",
>       "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^4.3.0",
>       "i18next-http-backend": "^1.0.15",
>       "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
>       "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
>       "proptypes": "^1.1.0",
>       "react": "^16.12.0",
>       "react-alice-carousel": "^1.17.2",
>       "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
>       "react-i18next": "^9.0.10",
>       "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.5",
>       "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
>       "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
>       "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
>       "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
>       "react-scripts": "^3.3.0"   },   "scripts": {
>       "start": "react-scripts start",
>       "build": "react-scripts build",
>       "test": "react-scripts test",
>       "eject": "react-scripts eject"   },   "eslintConfig": {
>       "extends": "react-app"   },   "browserslist": {
>       "production": [
>         ">0.2%",
>         "not dead",
>         "not op_mini all"
>       ],
>       "development": [
>         "last 1 chrome version",
>         "last 1 firefox version",
>         "last 1 safari version"
>       ]   },   "devDependencies": {
>       "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.8.3",
>       "css-loader": "^3.4.2"   } }

Comment: which version of react u r using .. hope u r using greater than 16.7.0 alpha (or 16.8 and+)

Comment: "react": "^16.12.0",

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleted `package.json` entries with `i18next`.
Deleted all node_modules folder
Reinstalled `npm install`
`npm install react-i18next i18next --save`
// when like to detect user language and load translation
`npm install i18next-http-backend i18next-browser-languagedetector --save`

This solved my problem.

Comment: fyi: a newer react-i18next guide can be found here: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb/stats

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react-i18next i18next --save
```

or

```
yarn add react-i18next i18next
```