# I am getting this error: Attempted import error: 'initReactI18next' is not exported from 'react-i18next'. This is what my i18next.js file looks like

Tags: reactjs, i18next, i18next-http-backend

This is my i18next.js file. I have downloaded all the dependencies and I was wondering why I am getting this error:

> Attempted import error: 'initReactI18next' is not exported from
> 'react-i18next'.

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
// don't want to use this?
// have a look at the Quick start guide 
// for passing in lng and translations on init

const Languages = ['en','ko','chi'];

i18n
  // load translation using http -> see /public/locales (i.e. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react/public/locales)
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
  .use(Backend)
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    whitelist: Languages,
    
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    }
  });


export default i18n;
```

Comment: Likely a problem with package installation. Try reinstalling the packages. npm install react-i18next i18next --save

Comment: I reinstalled it many times but the problem persists

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62429986/react-i18next-getting-error-attempted-import-error ?

Comment: Try: 
import * as ri18next from 'react-i18next';
console.log(ri18next);

Answer (score 0):

update the version using this command:

yarn:

```bash
yarn add react-i18next@11.8.15
```

npm:

```bash
npm i --save react-i18next@11.8.15
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
For my case, I created a new directory **@types** under **src** directory.
After that created type definition file **react-i18next.d.ts**.
Add the following content.

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          // here we will place our translations...
        }
      }
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

Now, that error was disappeared on my side.
Hope this can be help.